# Python, remove brackets from using values from a dict

Tags: python, brackets

```
mappe = {10 : [10, 1]}
pair = list(mappe.values())
liste = []
liste.append((pair) + [5, 6])
```

--> [[10,1], 5, 6]]

how can i remove the inner brackets?

Comment: Your brackets are unbalanced. Furthermore, what is your desired result? Do you just want a list `liste = [10, 1, 5, 6]`? In that case, just write `liste = pair + [5,6]`.

Comment: `liste = mappe[10] + [5, 6]` or `liste = list(mappe.values())[0] + [5, 6]`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `liste.extend()` instead. The function `append` adds the value that you pass in as a single element to a list, while `extend` will take an iterable object and put each item in the list as an item. Like this: `liste.extend(pair + [5,6])`

Answer (score 1):

Just another approach maybe?
it might do , depends on your task if you could elaborate please I'll gladly help

```py
mappe = {10 : [10, 1]}
#pair = list(mappe.values())
pair=[]
for element in mappe:
    for x in mappe[element]:
        pair.append(x)
    
liste = pair.copy()
liste+=[5, 6]

print(liste)
```